# Property does not exist error in TypeScript static method

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Below is my TypeScript code. In the static method it is throwing an error:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'typeof Person'.

What is the cause of this error and how do I fix it?

```
class Person {
    name: string = 'no name'
    constructor(protected id: string,){
    }
    showId=():string => {
        return this.id
    }
    static showname(){return this.name}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access class members in a static context. The name property also needs to be static.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Person {
    static name: string = 'no name'
    constructor(protected id: string,){
    }
    showId=():string => {
        return this.id
    }
    static showname(){return this.name}
}
```

or

```
class Person {
    name: string = 'no name'
    constructor(protected id: string,){
    }
    showId=():string => {
        return this.id
    }
    static showname(person: Person){return person.name}
}
```